# Работа с REST API.

Tags: json, api, rest

Есть сервис с API. Обмен запросами в формате JSON. Необходимо реализовать определенный функционал поверх API.

Пробовал отправлять AJAX запросы напрямую из клиента но в ответ приходит ошибка связанная с политикой безопасности и тем, что сервер расположен на другом домене (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *).

Понял, что единственный вариант — промежуточный сервер, через который будет происходить парсинг JSON запросов.

Подскажите, что почитать по этому вопросу и работающие примеры таких "приложений".

Comment: На чем написан клиент и "промежуточный сервер"?

Comment: php.Но если есть примеры на чем-то другом буду так же благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте материалы по CORS.

Кратко.  Вам нужно для каждого пути на сервере (к которому нужен доступ из другого домена) добавить обработчик метода OPTIONS. Этот обработчик должен возвращать код 200 вместе с заголовками, например

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
```

Вместо звездочки лучше указать домен, с которого будут делаться ajax-запросы.

Comment: Это сработает, разумеется, только если есть возможность конфигурировать сервер.

Comment: К сожалению доступ к серверу возможен только в рамках API

Comment: Т.е. серверный код не доступен? Тогда придётся делать промежуточный сервер (проксировать вызовы на ваш сервер).

Comment: Да, именно так, серверный код не доступен.По неопытности столкнулся с проблемами при написании собственного сервера, но найти какие-нибудь готовые примеры сервера взаимодействующего с любым API не смог. Возможно есть какие-нибудь фреймворки упрощающие написание, но к сожалению чего-то с рабочим примером также не нашел.

Comment: Свой серверный код сайта, в клиентской части которого вы делаете AJAX-запросы, вам доступен для редактирования?